# PHP execute python with opencv and dlib

Tags: php, python, opencv

I have a project which creates a morph image of two photos.

It is written with Python. Basically a prototype from here: https://github.com/matthewearl/faceswap

What I want to is to use it on my website to create dynamic images.

Well I have my cpanel server and python is in tbere already.. The problem is that this faceswap project doesn't work on the server but works really well on my pc..

What's the problem with this code?

```
<?php 
$result = exec('/usr/bin/python faceswap.py 1.jpg 2.jpg');
?>
```

Here are the files uploaded in my directory

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you can access that folder or any files in it ? Do you get any error messages? Also calling exec function might be forbidden on server

Comment: Yup! The permissions are set to 0777 already. I don't get any errors.

Comment: Can you run the command directly in the command line, does it work then?

Comment: My python command works fine on terminal but when i run in php it gives import dlib error. Please help me